# CMake project: can't include header from a subfolder

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a c++ project where I'm trying to take a part of a very large c++ codebase and reuse it for my purposes. I'm trying to set it up via cmake and I'm struggling with different ways to #include headers. The compiler successfully finds simple includes (like #include "a.h") but can't find an include from a subfolder (#include "a/a.h").

I've read the cmake docs and many answers on SO but haven't found an answer so far. Here's a test project with the this problem:

```
main.cpp
|
CMakeLists.txt
|
Folder_A
|    |
|   a.h
|
Folder_B
|    |
|   b.h
|
Folder_C
    |
    c.h
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```
project(test_project)

add_executable(test_project main.cpp)

target_include_directories(test_project PUBLIC "a")
target_include_directories(test_project PUBLIC "b")
target_include_directories(test_project PUBLIC "c")
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "a.h"


int main() {
    ...
}
```

a.h:

```
#include "b.h"
#include "c/c.h"

...
```

b.h:

```
#include "c.h"
...
```

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: To include files using relative paths, you should use `target_include_directories` with a base path for those relative paths.

Comment: `#include "b.h"
#include "c/c.h"` Be consistent, use one style everywhere.

Comment: Different styles come from the codebase I use. I really want to avoid refactoring it, it's just too big for me :)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
target_include_directories(test_project PUBLIC .)
```

along with the other target_include directives, this should add the root path of the project to the include search list and then you should be able to use the "a/a.h" syntax.